# Exporting classes and interfaces in a module in typescript for node.js package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, module, package

I have  one interface for Exception and one concrete class which inherited from that interface. I wish to export these types in a module as a node.js package.

iexp.ts

```
interface IException {}
```

exp.ts

```
class Exception implements IException {}
```

index.ts

```
module AB_Company {
    export IException;
    export Exception;
}
export {AB_Company};
```

The codes below just for seeing the scene. But I couldn't achieve to export this module.

the client will be used like this

```
import {AB_Company} from "AB_Company_Exception";
let exp:AB_Company.IException;
```

Comment: Please check "Needless Namespacing" in here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

Comment: @Dakamaz Did you find any solution ?